# Breaking up large JSON object

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I have a lot of files that I need to upload to my database, I am doing this through the browser and the server is having sizing issues with the data that is being sent to it and it rejects it. The server is not under my control in this context so I need to break up this object(s) into smaller objects before sending them to the server to get inserted into the database (rethinkdb if it matters). There is no order they need to be inserted in I just need to break up the file into smaller pieces.

I know I need a loop, but I do not understand how I can loop through 100 objects, save them as another object send them to the server, then start from 101 and so on....

Looping through all objects I get but this I cannot figure out or find examples for.

The code below is working for its purpose however it only goes to 250 then stops, it doesn't go past that.....

```
var lineData = jsonData.theData;
var newData = [];
var newLine;
//Shows on the browser console how many objects there are in the data
console.log(jsonData.theData.length);

//Goes through the Data and grabs the first 1000 lines
    for(var i = 0; i< 250; i++){
    newLine = lineData[i]
    newData.push(newLine);
    console.log(lineData[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Hint: create array of arrays. The outer array holds the inner arrays of 100 elements.

Comment: is there any way you can get the server admins to increase the post size?  seems like the best way to approach the problem to me.

Comment: I could however I would like to use this as a learning experience.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is loop through your objects and for every 100th object, push out your new array and start over. So something like:

```
var lineData = jsonData.theData;
var newData = [];

for (var i=0; i < lineData.length; i++) {
    newLine = lineData[i];
    newData.push(newLine);
    if (i && !(i % 100)) {
        // upload newData
        newData = [];
    }
}
// check if there's any data left
if (newData.length) {
    // upload the remaining data
}
```

Comment: Actually for the beginner (and anyone else) it would be more helpful to separate the responsibilities: so that the data split and data sending would not interleave. In that case you would avoid "upload" logic duplication and have clearer code.

Comment: @zerkms I understand, how would you do this? Do we need to save every array of 100 as a different variable? Or do we need to know that the server is done with its insert?

Comment: @illcrx not different variable, but as I already mentioned - as nested arrays. So you `push` the current array to another array, and continue splitting.

Comment: Will that solve my server size import issue? What is the reason for just restructuring the data?

Comment: It's not restructuring. You split it into a list of arrays of size 100, then send them one after another.

Comment: oh, so would I then do another loop after that restructuring loop to send it all, in similar fashion? (Im calling it restructuring)

Comment: @illcrx exactly. The point is that you split your code to 2 different logical parts: 1. changing data shape for further processing 2. processing it (uploading). That way you have a better structure and no need in code duplication and redundant checks (as in this very answer)

Comment: @zerkms: there is no duplicated code necessary in my answer if the upload part is simply a function you call. And no need to create a whole object full of duplicated data before you start uploading.

Comment: @MattBurland I'm not insisting, I'm fine with other people writing code that mixes multiple responsibilities. Just compare your and this code http://pastebin.com/8GgvA2S7 For me - what I posted looks MUCH more readable.